# Data processing with javascript

Tags: javascript, extjs, solr

I have a JSON response (from Solr) that is an array of objects containing multiple values. Like this:

```
    [
        {name: "Doug",
        status: "active",
        updated: "2013-10-24T18:20:58.39Z"
        }, 
        {name: "Matt",
        status: "inactive",
        updated: "2013-09-20T11:15:02.35Z"
        }, 
        {name: "Tom",
        status: "new",
        updated: "2013-09-20T17:34:45.68Z"
        },
        etc... 
   ]
```

I'm trying to process the data so it can be used in a graph (in EXTJS). So I would like to end up with a couple different arrays of objects to use as the model. The first one is a count of the occurences of each of the names, preferably without having to specify the names to count. With the result looking like this:

```
{name: "Doug", count: 5}, 
{name: "Matt", count: 10}, 
 etc...
```

The next thing I would like to get is a count of the statuses that were updated on each day, ignoring the time. Unlike the name count, I already know the possible values for "status". So just using the data I wrote above, I would like to see:

```
{date: "2013-10-24", active: 1, inactive: 0, new: 0},
{date: "2013-09-20", active: 0, inactive: 1, new: 1}
```

To me it seems like the best approach would be using Javascript's `reduce()` but I'm not sure how to handle the varying names for the first case, and dates in the second case. If there's anything I can pass to Solr to structure the data before it's sent, that would help too.

Comment: Using multiple Solr queries is an option I've considered, but it doesn't seem to simplify anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would first make a hashmap with the names and dates as keys. Then I'd iterate over the records and simply count the occurences. After that, all I need to do is convert the hashmap to the wanted format.

Here's the code for the first function:

```
function countByName(list) {
    var count = {}, ret = [];
    //First make a hashmap
    for(var i = 0, l = list.length; i < l; i++) {
        var item = list[i],
            nameCount = count[item.name];
        count[item.name] = !nameCount ? 1 : nameCount + 1;
    }
    //Then convert to the wanted format
    for(var name in count) {
        ret.push({name: name, count: count[name]});
    }
    return ret;
}
```

See this Fiddle for the rest of the code: http://jsfiddle.net/2rCgv/

Answer (score 0):

I know this has been asked a while back and answered but just for those who may check this up later on...You can do this in several ways with RichFlow. Available at https://github.com/ominibyte/richflow. In-browser testing is available on http://richflow.richboy.me.

You can do it in two passes or in a single pass. Let us say you have this as your data:

```
var data = [
    {name: "Doug",
    status: "active",
    updated: "2013-10-24T18:20:58.39Z"
    },
    {name: "Matt",
    status: "inactive",
    updated: "2013-09-20T11:15:02.35Z"
    },
    {name: "Tom",
    status: "new",
    updated: "2013-09-20T17:34:45.68Z"
    },
    {name: "Doug",
    status: "active",
    updated: "2013-10-24T18:20:58.39Z"
    }
];
```

In two passes, you could do:

```
var obj = Flow.from(
             Flow.from(data)
                 .groupBy("name")
          ).select(obj => {return {name: obj.key, count: obj.value.length}})
           .collect();
```

In a single pass you could do:

```
var obj = Flow.from(data)
              .partitionBy("name")
              .reduce([], (array, obj) => { 
                 array.push({name: obj.key, count: obj.value.length}); 
                 return array; 
              });
```

**EDIT**: Did not initially notice the second problem. For the second case you could either do:

```
 var times = Flow.from(data).partitionBy(input => input.updated.split("T")[0])
 .reduce([], (array, obj) => {
     array.push({
         date: obj.key, 
         active: Flow.from(obj.value).where(obj => obj.status == "active").count(),
         inactive: Flow.from(obj.value).where(obj => obj.status == "inactive").count(),
         "new": Flow.from(obj.value).where(obj => obj.status == "new").count()
     });
     return array;
 });
```

or you could go via this means:

```
var times = Flow.from(data).partitionBy(input => input.updated.split("T")[0])
 .reduce([], (array, obj) => {
     let groups = Flow.from(obj.value).groupBy("status");
     array.push({
         date: obj.key, 
         active: groups.active ? groups.active.length : 0,
         inactive: groups.inactive ? groups.inactive.length : 0,
         "new": groups["new"] ? groups["new"].length : 0
     });
     return array;
 });
```

Disclaimer: I wrote the library